# restoring button in table inside form from jquery does not allow .hover on button to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, button

I have a table inside a form. In each row there is on column that has a button. This button has a hover function and opens a specific popover for this table row on focus.

I am sending the form for validation and when page reloads i restore variables in the form. Every row of the table at reload is recreated with jquery in order to restore values in.

The specific column with the buttons it has not thing to restore it is only created again with jquery and added to the table.

At initial load of page the button works properly creating the popover.After validation and reload of the page the button .hover does not work and also the popover.

this is what i have in html part for the specific field with the button:

```
<td><button type="button" th:id="${code}" class="btn btn-info showList"  th:text="${code}" th:value="${code}"></button></td>
```

this is what i am using in the jquery as string and i add it in a specific row with other tds where Code comes as variable from outside:

```
'<td><button type="button" id="'+Code+'" class="btn btn-info showList" value="'+Code+'">'+Code+'</button></td>';
```

and this is the hover function which should trigger at first in order to see the popover on focus.

```
$(".showList").hover(function(){
    var Code=$(this).val();
    console.log(Code);
    getMilestoneTaskList(Code,runPopover);
});
```

What do i miss and the hover does not trigger when i create the button from jquery?

Thank you

Comment: look at event delegation

Comment: from what i see after reload there is no event listener to the element for mouseover as it is before. what can i do to fix?

Comment: how do i add this event listener with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be fixed if i use

```
$(document).on('keydown',"<selector>",function(){
        // set the function
});
```